# Can i clone Data Base Schema from one firebase project to other.?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase project which i am using for database and storage purpose and i want to clone this project and its db schema also.I need only table and relations only not data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no database schema in the Firebase Database. It's a schemaless JSON data store.

If you're looking to clone the data into another project, you can export it from either the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/) or the Firebase CLI. This gives you a `.json` file, that you can then import into the new project through the console or CLI again.

If you're looking to re-use the security rules from one project in another project, you will have to manually copy those rules from the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/) and add them to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't clone a project from the console, but you can export the json database (clicking the trhee dots menu from the database) and then using an online tool like [Liquid](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter).